# Are these java threads waiting on the lock it acquires?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, jstack

I'm looking at a jstack log and this is what i see:

> "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" #250 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9de0016000 nid=0x7e54 runnable [0x00007f9d6495a000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>       at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:534)
>       - locked <***0x00000006fa818a38***> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
>
> "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" #249 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9de000c000 nid=0x7e53 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f9d649db000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>       - waiting on <***0x00000006fa818a38***> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
>       at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:534)
>       - locked <***0x00000006fa818a38***> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
>
> "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" #248 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9de001a000 nid=0x7e52 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f9d64a5c000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>       - waiting on <***0x00000006fa818a38***> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
>       at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:534)
>       - locked <***0x00000006fa818a38***> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)

So, in this log, each of these three threads has managed to get the same lock and the bottom two threads are actually blocked waiting for the same lock.

Can someone please explain to me what this stack log means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **Thread-#2** has managed to get Object lock successfully and it is in **RUNNABLE** state. Other 2 threads, i.e., **Thread-#0** and **Thread-#1** are waiting for that lock to be released by **Thread-#2**. As long as **Thread-#2** holds the lock, **Thread-#0** and **Thread-#1** will remain locked and will be in a state **BLOCKED**.

If you have access to source code, You can review that code just to ensure if locking and unlocking is done in proper order and lock has been been held only for part of code where it is necessary. Remember these 2 threads are not in **WAIT** state but in **BLOCKED** state which is a step after **WAIT** state and just a step before getting in to **RUNNABLE** state as soon as lock is available.

There is no problem observed in this log snippet. This is not a deadlock scenario yet.

Answer (score 2):

The last two threads are waiting to be notified by using the instance of `ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner` as monitor, so the source of that will look something like this:

```
synchronized(asyncRunner) {
    // ...
    asyncRunner.wait();
    // ...
}
```

As soon as you call `wait`, the synchronization on `asyncRunner` is "released", i.e. other parts of the application can enter a block that is synchronized on that instance. In your particular case it seems that this has happened and the first thread's `wait`-call returned and it's currently processing some data that comes from it. You still see multiple `locked`-lines in the thread-dump to show you that the code is currently within a `synchronized`-block but as said, the "lock" is released when calling `wait`.

The technique you see here as a thread-dump is quite common before the concurrent-package was added to the JDK to avoid costly thread-creations. And your thread-dump looks like this kind of implementation. Here is a simple implementation how it might look like "under the hood":

```
// class ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner
private Deque<AsyncMessage> queue;

public synchronized void addAsyncMessage(AsyncMessage msg) {
    queue.add(msg);
    notifyAll();
}

public void start() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        PoolThread pt = new PoolThread(this);
        pt.start();
    }
}
```

The ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner`` starts PoolThreads and does a `notifyAll` if a new message to be processed is added.

```
// PoolThread

public PoolThread(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            AsyncMessage  msg = null;
            synchronized(parent) {
                parent.wait();
                if (!parent.queue.isEmpty()) {
                    msg = queue.removeFirst();
                }
            }
            if (msg != null) {
                processMsg(msg);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        // exit
    }
}
```

`notifyAll` will lead all `wait`-methods of all threads to return, so you have to check if the queue in the parent still contains data (sometimes `wait` returns even without a notification taken place, so you need this check even if not using `notifyAll`). If that's the case you start the processing method. You should do that outside the `synchronized`-block otherwise your async-processing class only processes one message at the time (unless, that's what you want - but then why run multiple `PoolThread`-instances?)

Answer (score 0):

What I can see and understand is that

**Thread-#2** is in Runnable state and has acquired a lock on an Object

> "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2"
>   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

**Thread-#1** and **Thread-#0** are waiting for that Object lock to be released and hence blocked right now.

> "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1"
>   "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0"
>   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor) at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) -
>   waiting on <0x00000006fa818a38>